# Argo Workflow: "Bad Request: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field"

Tags: unmarshalling, argo-workflows, argo

I have a Argo WorkflowTemplate that looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: test-container-command
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
  - name: main
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: command
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: "{{ inputs.parameters.command }}"
    env: # some predefined env
```

What I want to do is to create a WorkflowTemplate that can execute an arbitrary command specified by the input parameter `command`. That way, users of this WorkflowTemplate can supply the parameter `command` with an array of strings and then execute it like:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-run-
spec:
  workflowTemplateRef:
    name: test-container-command
  entrypoint: main
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: command
      value:
        - echo
        - hello
```

However, when I try to save this WorkflowTemplate, the Argo server gave me this error message:

```
Bad Request: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Container.workflow.spec.templates.container.command of type []string
```

It seems that Argo expects the field `.spec.templates.container.command` to be an array of strings, but it treat `"{{ inputs.parameters.command }}"` as a string, even though I'm trying to supply the parameter `command` with an array of strings.

Is there any way to achieve what I was trying to do as the WorkflowTemplate `test-container-command`, i.e. provide a WorkflowTemplate for the user to execute arbitrary commands with a predefined container and env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in error command should be list of strings.

You need to reformat your template to:

```
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["{{ inputs.parameters.command }}"]
```

Now argo should create your workflow without any problems

You could also use

```
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command:
      - "{{ inputs.parameters.command }}"
```

### Edit

As you want to run some commands within the image it would be much better instead of `container` use `script` template

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: test-container-command
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
  - name: main
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: command
      - name: extraEnv
    script:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [ "sh" ]
      env:
        - { name: ENV1, value: "foo" }
        - { name: ENV2, value: "{{ inputs.parameters.extraEnv }}" }
      source: |
        {{ inputs.parameters.command }}
```

Comment: If I use your WorkflowTemplate, can I pass the command with arguments, e.g. `echo hello` or `ls -l /tmp`?

Comment: ah, @johnlinp now I better understand what you want to du, let me edit the answer

Comment: I see your new WorkflowTemplate has a "script" template instead of "container" template. However, I want to pre-define some env in the WorkflowTemplate. Do "script" templates support env?

Comment: Another question: can I let my user pass another parameter `extraEnv` to specify extra env? For example, assume that the WorkflowTemplate already defines "ENV1=foo", can the user specify an extra env by passing `extraEnv` as "ENV2=bar"?

Comment: @johnlinp Yes, you can add another parameter `-name: extraEnv' (for parameters you can as well add `value: DefaultValue`)  and then in your `env`  add `- { name: ENV2, value: "{{ inputs.parameters.extraEnv }}"}` as well you could add `- { name: ENV1, value: "foo"}` it works just like in `container` template.
By the way. Would very much appreciate if you upvote the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: @johnlinp Added usage of env in example.